# Prove $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_n=0$ iff $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{1}{x_n}=\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

For $x_n \gt 0$ $\forall n=1,2,3,...$ Prove $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}x_n=0$$ iff $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{x_n}=+\infty$$
Working proof:

$\forall M>0, \exists N$ such that $x_n>M$, $\forall n \ge N$

$x_n>M\Rightarrow(1/x_n)<(1/M)$

Choose $N=[M]+1$ $\Rightarrow$ $\frac{1}{x_n}<(1/x_N)=(1/x_{[M]+1})$

I have no idea what the next step would be or if I'm even headed in the right direction...

Comment: There is no other conditions like $x_n \gt 0$?

Comment: $x_n>0$ $\forall n=1,2,3,...$ Sorry for that omission

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x_n \to 0$. Let $M$ in $\mathbb R+$, there exists $N$ such that for all $n ≥ N, |x_n| ≤ 1/M,$ so for all $n ≥ N, |1/x_n| ≥ M$ (since $x > 0 \to 1/x$ decreases). So $1/x_n \to +\infty$

The same for the other direction.

Answer (score 0):

NOt true take $$x_n =\frac{(-1)^n}{n}$$

Now Edit:

Let $A>0$ since $x_n\to0$ there exists $N\in\Bbb N$ such that, $n\ge N$ one has $$0<x_n<\frac{1}{A}~~~\forall n>N$$
that is $$\frac{1}{x_n}>A~~~\forall n>N$$

Hence $\frac{1}{x_n}\to+\infty$

Comment: @Lucas what ??? it depend on what the OP means. and which notation he use

Comment: For me $\to \infty$ means that $|x_n| \to + \infty$

Comment: @Lucas that is French notation as far as I know . and the OP did not use abs

Comment: @Lucas I disagree. He would say $|x_n|$ if he meant that.

Comment: Indeed, the statement as written is untrue

Comment: So $\infty = + \infty$ or $-\infty$ ?

Comment: I think it will be boring in France since many things like this is true lol